# Purification of water with ferric chloride

Tags: aqueous-solution, solubility, ph

Ferric chloride ($\ce{FeCl3}$) is a chemical used in water treatment. If ferric chloride is added to a water sample containing calcium bicarbonate, would the $\mathrm{pH}$ of the solution decrease or increase?

Answer (score 3):

*If I'd state that the pH drops, would you know why?*

If you dissolve $\ce{FeCl3}$ in water, a *hexaqua* complex is formed. These complexes are known as **cation acids**:

$$\ce{[Fe(H2O)6]^{3+} + H2O -> [Fe(OH)(H2O)5]^{3+} + H3O+}$$

Comment: But where does the Cl3 went in the case?

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix There's no $\ce{Cl3}$ but three chloride ions $\ce{Cl-}$ acting as counter ions to the aquo complex. They just float around, happily solvated by water molecules.